# What have JDK and IntelliJ to do for Java programming?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-11, software-distribution

New user here. I have just recently started learning Java programming. Can someone explain in their own words what JDK and IntelliJ have to do for Java programming? I did google, but the answers were not satisfying.

Comment: Please take the time to familiarize yourself with the Stack Overflow [help file](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Take particular note of the section covering what is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for this site. This site isn't the place to ask questions about fundamentals which are covered by other resources, including books and online tutorials.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and to learning Java. When those answers were not satisfying, at least spell out how they weren’t so we don’t waste our time just repeating them needlessly.

Comment: How JDK and IntelliJ IDEA work and their exact roles, that’s complicated stuff. Don’t expect to understand but at a superficial level from the outset. If you are able to type and run a Java program, satisfy yourself with that for now (and concentrate on learning the language and a few of the library classes). The rest can come later.

Comment: I would say JDK is a key component / software for building  Java and Intellij is an IDE which helps you to write/compile/run/debug the code (E.g: Like you use wordpad to create text files and type/format your text). IDEs makes the working with code easier.

Answer (score 1):

from Wikipedia, **Java is a high-level, class-based, object-oriented programming language that is designed to have as few implementation dependencies as possible.** JDK or Java Development Kit is a set of tools needed for developing a Java Application, like compiler, interpreter and other tools. For writing a Java program you can use any text editor and save your files with `.java` extension.
At older times people used to type code in basic editors like notepad.

But now things has changed. To easily understand your code there are some softwares which can format your code, highlight syntax, compile and run your project in just one click, Find your errors at the same time writing the code and many more. A software like that is called an **IDE** or ***Integrated Development Environment***. There are many IDEs available now and IntelliJ is one of them. Other than IntelliJ, there are many IDes like

- [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)
- [NetBeans](https://netbeans.apache.org/)
- [BlueJ](https://www.bluej.org/)
- [DrJava](http://www.drjava.org/)
- [JDeveloper](https://www.oracle.com/application-development/technologies/jdeveloper.html)
- and many more

I think now your doubt is cleared.